# Querying an XML column - returning relational data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

I have a problem where I must return data in a SQL query that is contained in an XML column.  I have some tentative results, but am having a difficult time making quick headway.  So far I have this:

XML (example for one row):

```
<root>
  <property>
    <Name>Boolean</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Name>Integer</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </property>
</root>
```

SQL:

```
select ItemID,
       boolean = CASE WHEN CF.exist('/root/property/Name[text() = "Boolean"]') = 1 
        THEN CF.value('(/root/property/Value)[1]', 'varchar(32)') END,
       [integer] = CASE WHEN CF.exist('/root/property/Name[text() = "Integer"]') = 1 
        THEN CF.value('(/root/property/Value)[2]', 'varchar(32)') END
from 
       [TTS].[dbo].[tblInItem]
```

And the resulting data is this:

[image]

You can see that row 4 is populating a boolean where there should be an integer.  This is because the XML for that line is:

```
<root>
  <property>
    <Name>Boolean</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Name>Another Boolean</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Name>Integer</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </property>
</root>
```

So, how can I replace the singleton `[2]` in `CF.value('(/root/property/Value)[2]', 'varchar(32)')` with something that returns the node position?

I also recognize that there are likely a number of more elegant solutions, and am open to any of those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the case statement and put the predicate on property name in the xPath expression where you get the value.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2401/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T(ItemID int identity primary key, CF xml);

insert into T(CF) values('<root>
  <property>
    <Name>Boolean</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Name>Integer</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </property>
</root>');

insert into T(CF) values('<root>
  <property>
    <Name>Boolean</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Name>Another Boolean</Name>
    <Value>True</Value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <Name>Integer</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </property>
</root>');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select T.ItemID,
       T.CF.value('(/root/property[Name/text() = "Boolean"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as Boolean,
       T.CF.value('(/root/property[Name/text() = "Integer"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as Integer
from T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2401/1/0)**:

```
| ItemID | Boolean | Integer |
|--------|---------|---------|
|      1 |    True |       0 |
|      2 |    True |       0 |
```